# Angular 9 Multiple row dynamic form validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms, angular9, dynamicform

I have created a simple dynamic, when the number of rows is selected from a drop down, the rows are created with validation error displaying in each field.
Can anyone help me to display the **validation error for all the rows in one place**, which means it validates all the fields in the rows and the validation error for a particular filed is displayed only once below the form.

Here's my code:
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'employeelist';
  buttonstatus = false;
  isSubmitted = '';
  submitted = false;
  userTable: FormGroup;
  control: FormArray;
  employeelist: any = [];
  selectedGroup: any;
  counts = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "One"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Two"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Three"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Four"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Five"
  }
  ];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userTable = this.fb.group({
      tableRows: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  initiateForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      lastname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]],
      dob: ['', [Validators.required]],
      mob: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$")]],
      isEditable: [false]
    });
  }

  get getFormControls() {
    const control = this.userTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    return control;
  }

  addRow() {
    if (this.selectedGroup) {
      let control = this.userTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
      var count = this.selectedGroup.id;
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        control.push(this.initiateForm());
      }

      this.buttonstatus = true;
      this.isSubmitted = 'true';
    }
    else {
      this.isSubmitted = 'false';
    }
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    const control = this.userTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(index);
    if (control.length == 0) {
      this.buttonstatus = false;
    }
  }

  doneRow(group: FormGroup) {
    if (group.valid) {
      group.get('isEditable').setValue(true);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.userTable.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    // display form values on success
    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.userTable.value));
    this.employeelist = this.userTable.value;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Employee List</h1>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Employee
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" [disabled]='buttonstatus'>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of counts" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button (click)="addRow()" [disabled]='buttonstatus' class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                        type="button"> GO </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="isSubmitted == 'false'">
                <sup>*</sup>Please select the no. of employees
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form [formGroup]="userTable" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <ng-container formArrayName="tableRows"
                            *ngFor="let group of getFormControls.controls; let i=index">
                            <tr [formGroupName]="i">
                                <th>{{i+1}}</th>
                                <td><input type="text" required formControlName="firstname"
                                        class="form-control input-sm"
                                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').touched) && getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors }" />
                                    <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors)"
                                        class="invalid-input">
                                        <div *ngIf="getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors.required">First
                                            Name is required</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors.minlength">First
                                            Name must be at least 3 characters</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" required class="form-control input-sm" formControlName="lastname"
                                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').touched) && getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors }" />
                                    <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors)"
                                        class="invalid-input">
                                        <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors.required">Last
                                            Name is required</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors.minlength">Last
                                            Name must be at least 1 characters</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" required formControlName="email"
                                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').touched) && getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors }" />
                                    <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors)"
                                        class="invalid-input">
                                        <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors.required">Email is
                                            required</div>
                                        <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors.pattern">Enter
                                            Valid Email</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" required formControlName="dob"
                                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').touched) && getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').errors }" />
                                    <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').errors)"
                                        class="invalid-input">
                                        <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').errors.required">Date of
                                            Birth is required</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm" required formControlName="mob"
                                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').touched) && getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors }" />
                                    <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors)"
                                        class="invalid-input">
                                        <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors.required">Mobile
                                            no is required</div>
                                        <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors.pattern">Enter Valid
                                            Mobile No</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1" value="Submit" (click)="doneRow(group)" /> -->
                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Delete"
                                        (click)="deleteRow(i)" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>                            
                        </ng-container>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [disabled]='!buttonstatus'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot of the validation error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jgDp.png)

Kindly solicit your help in displaying the validation errors in a separate list numbered below the form
For eg: if the there are three rows and the only first name validation error in one row and if its last name and email validation error in another and third one doesnt have any validation error, Can I display the validation errors like this, instead of displaying the error on each field as shown in the screenshot:

1. First name is required
2. Last Name is required
3. Email is required

Any help would be great, Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Validation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1cef.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Employee List</h1>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Employee
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" [disabled]='buttonstatus'>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of counts" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button (click)="addRow()" [disabled]='buttonstatus' class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"> GO </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid" *ngIf="isSubmitted == 'false'">
                <sup>*</sup>Please select the no. of employees
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form [formGroup]="userTable" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <ng-container formArrayName="tableRows" *ngFor="let group of getFormControls.controls; let i=index">
                            <tr [formGroupName]="i">
                                <th>{{i+1}}</th>
                                <td><input type="text" required formControlName="firstname" class="form-control input-sm" />
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" required class="form-control input-sm" formControlName="lastname" />
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" required formControlName="email" />
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" required formControlName="dob" />
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="tel" class="form-control input-sm" required formControlName="mob" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1" value="Submit" (click)="doneRow(group)" /> -->
                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Delete" (click)="deleteRow(i)" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <ol *ngIf="submitted">
                    <li *ngFor="let group of getFormControls.controls; let i=index">
                        <ul>
                            <li *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors)">
                                <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors)" class="invalid-input">
                                    <div *ngIf="getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="getFormControls.controls[i].get('firstname').errors.minlength">First Name must be at least 3 characters</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors)">
                                <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors)" class="invalid-input">
                                    <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf="getFormControls.controls[i].get('lastname').errors.minlength">Last Name must be at least 1 characters</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors)">
                                <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors)" class="invalid-input">
                                    <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors.required">Email is required
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('email').errors.pattern">Enter Valid Email</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').errors)">
                                <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').errors)" class="invalid-input">
                                    <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('dob').errors.required">Date of Birth is required</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors)">
                                <div *ngIf="((submitted || getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').touched) &&  getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors)" class="invalid-input">
                                    <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors.required">Mobile no is required</div>
                                    <div *ngIf=" getFormControls.controls[i].get('mob').errors.pattern">Enter Valid Mobile No</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [disabled]='!buttonstatus'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.